# What would be the best small signal model to the following LF RFID circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, rfid, modeling

I'm trying to analyse a LF RFID circuit's antenna of a [TMS3705](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms3705.pdf?ts=1645810799936&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) base station using simulation. I want to estimate the frequency response and  the Q factor. The intention is to do it for two different circuits of antenna and to compare with each other.

The transmission model is easier to understand and I already did it, now I'm supponsing receiver mode.  I dont know very well how to model a induction on the coil antenna, but I can imagine three situations:

1. To use a circuit of a RFID tag that I know (I indicated this circuit on the figure 1 below). I suppose the mutual inductance equal to 1 to minimize the influence of the tag. I know that this way the analysis will be not only on the antenna's circuit but on the tag as well. However, how the intention is to compare two circuits maybe it would be a valid option.
2. To consider an A.C power supply in parallel with the coil, like in the figure 2.
3. To exchange the coil by a A.C. power suply

Figure 1:
[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

In each figure I put a label with the corresponding pin name of [TMS3705](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms3705.pdf?ts=1645810799936&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). Below are data sheet excerpts which I relied on.

> For diagnosis, the SENSE pin is loaded on-chip with a switchable
> resistor to ground so that the internal switchable resistor and the
> external SENSE resistor form a voltage divider, while the internal
> resistor is switched off in read mode.
>
> When the full bridge is not active, the two driver outputs are
> switched to ground.

I don't know what would be the best approach or if all of them are wrong. Does anyone have any observations or tips to make?

Comment: Table 7-1 shows antenna as 422 µH at 134 kHz , yet you have 26  µH . Why? Also don't put a 0 ohm signal across a parallel LC resonating antenna

Comment: I'm not using the example circuit on the datasheet, this is not my objective. The circuit already exist